# change origin points of multiple objects to same z coordinate

Tags: 3d-view

How can i change just the origin points of multiple objects?

I know, how i can move them, but i want to set them all to the same z-coordinate.

[image]

If i choose this:

[image]

I can move them with G -> Z ...but i want them to have the same z-coordinate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select first and second option as well:

[image: Options showing Origins and Locations enabled in Transform]

Press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to align them on Z axis at the same height; then use <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to move them exactly where you wish.

[image: Screenshot showing origins moved to be on the same line]

Note: Choose active element as the pivot point:

[image: Close up of active element selected as pivot point in the header]

Comment: Works, thank you! I just added a little note, because that's important too, hope you don't mind.

Comment: I don't mind, I didn't know that because I used median point and it worked as well so I didn't include it into an answer